# Wait Message when submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to do something very simple. I have one button in my page..

```
<body>
<img src="images/myloadingimage.png" style="display: none;" id="loading_image">
    <form id="myform" type="post" action="test.php" >
        Name : <input type="name" id="name" value="" /><br />
        LName : <input type="lname" id="lname" value="" /><br />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Now what I want is when the user presses this submit button.. It shows that "loading" gif animation until form submission completes. I want in Javascript. How do i implement this.

Comment: You want to submit form with AJAX?

Comment: just am sending the post variables to test.php, if possible both javascript and ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Jquery BlockUI plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) with jquery Ajax call.

for showing loading message you need to write

```
$.blockUI();
```

for hiding loading message you need to write

```
$.unblockUI();
```

There are also lots of customizations available for this plugin. [Check the demos here](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos)

[This link will help you to integrate Jquery BlockUI plugin with Jquery Ajax call](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/565_Using_BlockUI_Plugin_with_JQuery_Ajax_API.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I like to park a div off screen like so the image is preloaded:

```
<div id="LoadingDiv" style="left: -200px;">
    <div>
        <img src="images/loading.gif" title="Loading" />
        <div class="LoadingTitle">Loading...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then use a bit of JQuery:

```
var div = $("#LoadingDiv");
function LoadingDiv() {
    div.animate({
        left: parseInt(div.css('left'), 10) == 0 ?
          -div.outerWidth() * 2 :
          0
    });
}
```

(that's the simpler version)

Answer (score 1):

simply over write default form action and display the loading icon and remove on successful completion of your ajax request.

**sample:**

```
   $("form").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // stops the default action
            $("#loader").show(); // shows the loading screen
            $.ajax({
                url: test.php,
                type: "POST"
                success: function (returnhtml) {
                    $("#loader").hide(); // hides loading sccreen in success call back
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: $.ajax makes GET request by default, you want `type: POST`.

Comment: yes, when we click on the submit button post variables sending to test.php.

Comment: @MedojuNarendar yes it will make post request to test.php

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use ajax you can do like this. Before displaying the loading icon, you will also need to add code for any javascript validation if needed.

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(e){
     $("#loading_image").show();
     $("#myform").submit();
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to handle form onsubmit event manually, making POST AJAX request. Before request you show loading image and once it's complete you need to hide it again.

Check the code with comments on important places:

```
$('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {

    // Prevent default browser form submission with page reload
    e.preventDefault();

    // Show loading indicator
    var $loading = $('#loading_image').show();

    // Make POST request with form parameters
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize()).done(function(response) {

        // Hide loading image once request is complete
        $loading.hide();

        // Do something with responce
        console.log(response);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through jQuery.

Make a jQuery ajax POST request

```
//Do the image load here
//now make the ajax call
$.post("test.php",$('#myform').serialize(),function(data){
     //if success
     //remove gif image
     //continue with whatever you want
},"json");//incase you need a json reply
```